# AWS DMS - Selecting columns from multiple tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

Is it possible to select columns from multiple destination tables and include them in a single source table in AWS DMS? For example:

I have the following tables in a Postgres database:

```
users {
  id (PRIMARY KEY)
  name
}
```

```
trips {
  id (PRIMARY KEY)
  user_id
  number
}
```

I want to be able to create a rule/task in DMS to select columns `trips.number` and `users.name` for a table called `trips_with_user_name`.

Answer (score 0):

DMS does not support transformations/aggregations to data. You should consider using AWS Glue to join multiple source tables and send it to a common table in target.

https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc